# Pandas MultiIndex: Partial indexing on second level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data-set open in Pandas with a 2-level MultiIndex. The first level of the MultiIndex is a unique ID (**SID**) while the second level is time (**ISO_TIME**). A sample of the data-set is given below.

```
                                     SEASON NATURE  NUMBER
SID           ISO_TIME                                  
2020138N10086 2020-05-16 12:00:00    2020     NR      26
              2020-05-16 15:00:00    2020     NR      26
              2020-05-16 18:00:00    2020     NR      26
              2020-05-16 21:00:00    2020     NR      26
              2020-05-17 00:00:00    2020     NR      26
2020155N17072 2020-06-02 18:00:00    2020     NR      30
              2020-06-02 21:00:00    2020     NR      30
              2020-06-03 00:00:00    2020     NR      30
              2020-06-03 03:00:00    2020     NR      30
              2020-06-03 06:00:00    2020     NR      30
2020327N11056 2020-11-21 18:00:00    2020     NR     103
              2020-11-21 21:00:00    2020     NR     103
              2020-11-22 00:00:00    2020     NR     103
              2020-11-22 03:00:00    2020     NR     103
              2020-11-22 06:00:00    2020     NR     103
2020329N10084 2020-11-23 12:00:00    2020     NR     104
              2020-11-23 15:00:00    2020     NR     104
              2020-11-23 18:00:00    2020     NR     104
              2020-11-23 21:00:00    2020     NR     104
              2020-11-24 00:00:00    2020     NR     104
```

I can do `df.loc[("2020138N10086")]` to select rows with *SID=2020138N10086* or `df.loc[("2020138N10086", "2020-05-17")]` to select rows with *SID=2020138N10086* and are on *2020-05-17*.
What I want to do, but not able to, is to partially index using the second level of MultiIndex. That is, select all  rows on *2020-05-17*, irrespective of the *SID*.
I have read through [Pandas MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) which explains how indexing is done with MultiIndex. But nowhere in it could I find how to do a partial indexing on the second/inner level of a Pandas MultiIndex. Either I missed it in the document or it is not explained in there.
So, is it possible to do a partial indexing in the second level of a Pandas MultiIndex?
If it is possible,  how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with slicing. See the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers).

Example for your dataframe:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), '2020-05-17'), :]
```

Comment: Do you know why the tuple requires slice(None) instead of simply using a colon?  That's what I was trying initially and it essentially seem to be the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=df.reset_index()
dates_rows= df[df["ISO_TIME"]=="2020-05-17"]
```

If you want you can convert it back to a multi-level index again, like below

```
df.set_index(['SID', 'ISO_TIME'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to partial index with the inner index only on a MultiIndex dataframe?

Comment: I tried your method, but it isn't selecting all rows (sometimes an empty dataframe is returned) for the date. For example, there's 4 rows on **'2020-05-16'**, but when I do `df[df['ISO_TIME']=='2020-05-16']`, I get an empty dataframe.
Also, on **'2020-05-17'**, there's more than one records in the dataframe ( not shown in the question), but `df[df['ISO_TIME']=='2020-05-17'` only selects the row with `ISO_TIME='2020-05-17 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [cross-section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#cross-section)

```py
df.xs('2020-05-17', level="ISO_TIME")
```